# Handling multiple axios get requests inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component like this:

```
class Example extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       name: '',
       address: '',
       phone: ''
     }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     //APIcall1 to get name and set the state
     //i.e., axios.get().then(this.setState())
     //APIcall2 to get address and set the state
     //APIcall3 to get phone and set the state
    }
 }`
```

As you can see I am making three API get requests to get the details and setting the state three times after getting the data. Due to this, I am getting this error:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

By the way, I am not causing a state change in the render method. Anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `axios.get` returns a promise, you can link them together before calling setState. For example using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
componentDidMount() {
  Promise.all([
    APIcall1, // i.e. axios.get(something)
    APIcall2,
    APIcall3
  ]).then(([result1, result2, result3]) => {
    // call setState here
  })
}
```

Just beware that if any of the api calls fail, Promise.all will catch, and setState won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

In axios you have the method `axios.all`:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

Or you can use the standard `Promise.all`:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

Promise.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(data => {
    // Both requests are now complete
  });
```