# How to post 2 APIs at a time while doing on submit method using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a small project where i have created a form and i want to add file also. Form having one API and for uploading files having another api.

```
 handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { firstName, LastName, phoneNumber} = this.state;
    const data = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      phoneNumber
    };
axios.post(`/api/Form`, data, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
```

for files:

```
 uploadFile = (files) => {

    var formData = new FormData();

    files.map((file, index) => {
      formData.append(`file${index}`, file);
    });
fetch('/api/uploadFiles', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: formData,
     })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(success => {

       })
       .catch(error => console.log(error)
       );
  }
```

I couldn't able to figure it out how to write both apis in submit method. Can anyone help me in this query? I'm not sure how to give 2 apis in submit method.

Comment: Call those api's in two different functions and you can call both the functions inside ```handleSubmit``` submit method.. Then finally can use ```Promise.all``` to get the results..  This https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964978/7785337 or something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529764/7785337 should help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your formData to State

```
uploadFile = (files) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    files.map((file, index) => {
      formData.append(`file${index}`, file);
    });
    this.setState({file:formData});
}
```

Then Post your 2 API's in handleSubmit

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, file} = this.state;
    const data = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      phoneNumber
    };
    axios.post(`/api/Form`, data, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then(res => {
       console.log(res)
       console.log(res.data);
    }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
    });
    if(file) {
       fetch('/api/uploadFiles', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: file,
       }).then(response => response.json()).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solution Works great!. Thanks for solving my problem. I have another query.

Comment: Yes Sandhya Tell me your query

Comment: If we don't have any API for file upload then how do we handle and submit the file in the form. Could you please assist me?

Comment: Check the file has any data using if condition. If file has anything then call the upload API. If you don't have any upload API no need to pass file. Check the updated one

Comment: We don't have any upload api then how do we do for uploading

Comment: If you don't have any API just create one in Backend. Or check 'api/Form' endpoint has any image field, if yes, then post your image file with 'api/Form' endpoint.

Comment: Yes, we have file: [ ] in `api/Form` and it takes the path of the file. for example: if i want to upload image.jpg then in swagger it is taking as //download//user//image.jpg

Comment: I can't get clearly, send your `file` as what mentioned in swagger, And it takes the path of the file only check your backend logic. Is it working fine in swagger?

Comment: Change your headers to `'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata'`